# SQL if select statement returns no rows then perform alternative select statement

Tags: sql

Basically, what syntex would allow me to achieve the title statement?

```
If (select statement 1) returns 0 rows THEN (select statement 2) else (select statement 3)
```

So that the sql returns results from either statement 2 or 3
I've looked for a way to do this but nothing I've found so far seems to exactly address the if requirements.

Comment: strange objective. what is the physical sense of it?

Comment: which RDBMS? do you want to do this in pure sql, or as part of a script?

Comment: Do you mean "if no rows from 1st select, use a 2nd select", rather than usign 3 tables?? And are all result sets the same shape (You wouldn't change the resultset dynamically because the contract then changes.)

Answer (score 36):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT field FROM table)
BEGIN
SELECT field FROM table2
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT field FROM table3
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go...

```
IF ((select count(*) from table1)= 0)
BEGIN
Select * from table2
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT * from table3
END
```

Comment: Most optimizers are smart enough to finish evaluating an `EXISTS` clause as soon as one matching row has occurred. Some optimizers are too dumb to realize that you're planning to compare a `COUNT(*)` against 0, and will evaluate all rows to compute the count.

Comment: Agreed...if 0 is all we want to compare with; EXISTS is all that makes sense! Other cases count might help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the lack of feedback. Someone else in the office took an interest and came up with this:

```
select * from (
        select *
              , (SELECT Count(*) 
                   FROM users 
                  WHERE version_replace = 59 AND moderated = 1) AS Counter 
          FROM users WHERE version_replace = 59 AND moderated in (0,1)
     ) AS y
where Counter = 0 and Moderated = 0
   or Counter > 0 and Moderated = 1
ORDER By ID DESC
```

Which does what I need.