# How do I select an alternative if my first Select result is null?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my SQL, I have the following:

```
SELECT 
    [PhotoImageID]
    ,[PhotoImage]
    ,[PhotoLinkID]
    ,[Comment]
    ,CONVERT(varchar, [Timestamp], 13) AS [Timestamp]
FROM 
    [Exchequer].[dbo].[TBL_SS_PhotoImages] WITH (nolock) 
WHERE
    PhotoLinkID = @stCode
```

If no record exists, I want to send a default one:

```
SELECT 
    [PhotoImageID]
    ,[PhotoImage]
    ,[PhotoLinkID]
    ,[Comment]
    ,CONVERT(varchar, [Timestamp], 13) AS [Timestamp]
FROM 
    [Exchequer].[dbo].[TBL_SS_PhotoImages] WITH (nolock) 
WHERE
    PhotoImageID = 1
```

I have looked at `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` but I can't see how to make it do what I want here.

Comment: may be try similar approach to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6466346/1479895

Comment: Why `NOLOCK`? This means `read dirty data while taking excessive locks`. You don't need it. If the query is slow you have a different problem. Missing indexes perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if exists to check if your query contains records.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT top 1 FROM [Exchequer].[dbo].[TBL_SS_PhotoImages] with (nolock) where PhotoLinkID = @stCode)
Begin
SELECT [PhotoImageID]
      ,[PhotoImage]
      ,[PhotoLinkID]
      ,[Comment]
      ,convert(varchar,[Timestamp],13) as [Timestamp]
  FROM [Exchequer].[dbo].[TBL_SS_PhotoImages] with (nolock) where PhotoLinkID = @stCode
End
Else
Begin
   SELECT [PhotoImageID]
      ,[PhotoImage]
      ,[PhotoLinkID]
      ,[Comment]
      ,convert(varchar,[Timestamp],13) as [Timestamp]
  FROM [Exchequer].[dbo].[TBL_SS_PhotoImages] with (nolock) where PhotoImageID = 1
End
```

Comment: This is definitely *wrong*. It executes *two* queries when only one is needed. Oops, *three* queries.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it, it's what I would've answered

Comment: @Birel executing the same query *two* times, scanning the table multiple times is definitely wrong. Using `NOLOCK` is *very* wrong and will lead to bad data. If the original query was so slow that the OP used `NOLOCK`, *this* one is three times as bad.

Comment: @Birel besides, Gordon Linoff already posted the correct, fast answer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how 3 times??? queries are written in if-else statements...

Comment: Obligatory reading by Aaron Bertrand: [Bad Habits: ](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). Using NOLOCK can even return the wrong result, if it doesn't actually throw an error

Comment: @Atk only one query is needed. And yet, the `IF` runs the query once. If that succeeds, the *same* query is executed again in the first branch. If not, a similar query is executed in the second. So it's just twice as bad, but it's still very, very bad

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Nolock was in OP's query. And the question was different.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably, you want one row.  If so, I think this is the simplest method:

```
SELECT TOP (1) [PhotoImageID], [PhotoImage], [PhotoLinkID],[Comment],
       convert(varchar(255), [Timestamp], 13) as [Timestamp]
FROM [Exchequer].[dbo].[TBL_SS_PhotoImages]  wh
WHERE PhotoLinkID = @stCode OR PhotoImageID = 1
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN PhotoLinkId <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END);
```

Actually, if multiple rows are needed, this is easy to modify.  Just use `TOP (1) WITH TIES`.

Notes:

- Only use `NOLOCK` if you really understand what it does.
- Always use a length with `VARCHAR()`.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff it is PhotoLinkID or PhotoImageID  in where clause. Two different columns are in game. I believe you have not seen this... Same happen to me in first look...

Comment: @VBoka it's trivial to change the `WHERE` expression  to `OR PhotoImageID = 1`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the question was not about the use of NOLOCK

Comment: @SimpleSimon neither is the comment. You probably wanted to post the comment under the question. As Gordon explains though, NOLOCK should **only** be used if one clearly understands what it does - read dirty data with a chance of duplication and corruption. It's a **very** strong smell suggesting something is wrong. Most likely a performance problem covered up by using NOLOCK